# How Automatically On "Content Blocker" Extension in Safari section?

Tags: ios, safari, extension-methods, adblock

I am creating an Ad Blocker. I am just trying to Automatically on safari extension of "Content Blocker". I went through examples but did't found any solution. Is there any way to "ON" extension or manually we have to start it?

Answer (score 1):

On iOS, Safari Content Blockers are disabled by default.

There is no way to automatically enable them from your app. You must instruct the user to:

1. Open the **Settings** app.
2. Go to **Safari** > **Content Blockers**.
3. Toggle on your Content Blocker extension.

On macOS (as of 10.12), a similar rule applies: Content Blocker extensions (bundled with your app) are disabled by default, and must be toggled on *by the user* in **Safari Preferences** > **Extensions**.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to test your "personal AdBlock program", first prepare a dummy HTML, with this line `<div class="ads">hello</div>`,

next apply your "personal AdBlock program", assuming it is JavaScript/CSS based and not proxy-like, you either hide, or remove the element (Node) from the DOM.

for example:
`document.querySelector('div[class*="ads"]')` -- this is nice and (very) generic way to find the element.

this is how to hide "the ads"
`document.querySelector('div[class*="ads"]').style.display="none";`
or, to make it stronger, related to other rules on the page, make it a local style + important notifier: `document.querySelector('div[class*="ads"]').style.cssText="display:none !important;"  ;`

you can also remove the element (Node) from the DOM:
`var e = document.querySelector('div[class*="ads"]')` follow by:
`e.parentNode.removeChild(e);`

now, you probably want to see that "YOUR ADBLOCK" worked,
later (after the page has loaded, and your javascript code runned) type:
`console.log(null === document.querySelector('div[class*="ads"]') ? "removed(success)" : "still here(failed)")`

note that for this example (to make things simple) I assume there is only one div with that class in the page (avoiding loops :) ).

if you've just going to hide the element, you should query its current (most updated) style-condition, using a native method exist under `window`:

`console.log("none" === window.getComputedStyle(document.querySelector('div[class*="ads"]')) ? "hidden(success)" : "still here(failed)")`

Enjoy!